# Как настроить API в контакте для автоматического добавления постов?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Пробую настроить автоматическую публикацию постов группе методом wall.get
При запуске на локальном сервере - 'success!' но в группе ничего не добавляется, в чем ошибка?

**post_data.text**

```
"Тестовое сообщение"
```

**token.txt**:

```
'токен из 85 символов" // получен из группы
```

**wall.post.php**

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">


<?php

$group_id = '-9894839';   
$token = file_get_contents('token.txt');
$api_ver = "5.80";
$text = file_get_contents('post_data.txt');
$url = sprintf('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?');
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_POST           => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
    "owner_id"      => $group_id,
    "form_group" => 1,
    "message"       =>$text,
    "access_token"  =>$token,
    "v"             =>$api_ver,

),
    CURLOPT_URL =>$url,
    ));
$query = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!$query){
  printf('Error');
  exit;
}
else{
  printf('$success');
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сперва выясните нет ли ошибки в теле запроса с помощью функции `printf(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));` . Если Вы получите ответ 200, то значит ошибка в API. Добавьте вывод сообщения с помощью `var_dump($query);` . Таким образом Вы получите сообщение от ВКонтакте, которое позволит исправить неверный аргумент в запросе (токен, ID группы и т.п.) .

Comment: а куда именно нужно эти функции подставить?

Comment: @ruben Сразу после curl_exec .

Comment: да,  ошибка 200 а вывод сообщения большой https://pastebin.com/gt92gLns  ну а что в API не так может быть?

Comment: 200 это не ошибка (https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP). Значит Ваш код работает правильно, но аргументы он получает неверные. Судя по ответу от ВКонтакте токен неверный. Учтите, что с помощью токена сообщества Вы не сможете опубликовать запись. Вам нужно передать токен пользователя, у которого есть права не ниже редактора.

Answer (score 0):

*Во-первых*, должен быть использован `access_token` пользователя, полученный от standalone-приложения, а не самого сообщества, так как `callback` не для этого предназначен.

*Во-вторых*, можно делать куда проще код, вот например

**post_data.txt**

```
Тут будет находиться текст
```

**token.txt**

```
Тут будет находиться access_token
```

**wall.post.php**

```
<?php

$group_id = '-156086527';   
$token = file_get_contents('token.txt');
$text = file_get_contents('post_data.txt');
$version = '5.80';

$post = curl('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', [
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v' => $version,
    'group_id' => $group_id,
    'message' => $text
]);

print_r($post);

function curl ($url, $params = [])
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    if (isset($params)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $content;
}
```

Делаем запрос, и получаем следующий `json` ответ

```
{"response":{"post_id":1312}}
```